# How do I assign an iterating property/variable on an object?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to export data into an analysis but I'm doing something wrong.

Basically I have a `report` that has between 1 and 9 `subject`s. 
I am writing this export-tool from scratch, the data is from a legacy system.

The analysis should be exported as CSV, with columns like:

`'report_id';'subject0';'subject1'`...all the way to `'subject9'`

I tried `foreach`-ing over an array of subjects of a report, and keeping count:

```
$iterator=0;
foreach ($subjects as $subject)
{
  $this->analysis [$report_id] ->subject${iterator} = (string)$subject;
  $iterator++;
}
```

**Update**
Because I may not use variables on the right side of the arrow operator, I've rewritten it as a very un-DRY switch:

```
$iterator = 0;
foreach ($categories as $subject)
  {
    switch ($iterator)
    {
    case 0:
      $this->analysis [$report_id] ->subject0 =  $subject;
      break;
    case 1:
      $this->analysis [$report_id] ->subject1 =  $subject;
      break;
    case 2:
      $this->analysis [$report_id] ->subject2 =  $subject;
      break;
    // I have 6 more cases, just to fill all 9 subjects, snipped for brevity

    default:
      //some errorhandling //snipped for brevity
      break 2;
    } 
    $iterator++;
  }
```

`$this->analysis [$report_id]` is an object that stores strings as follows:
`$this->analysis [$report_id] ->subject0 = "foo"`
The `$report_id` is a result of an earlier loop.
`$this->analysis` is an array filled with (`report`)objects that are included in the analysis.

I hope that anyone can find the flaw and point me in the direction of DRY-ing up my implementation. Bonus points for the philosophy behind it, so that I'm not only helped with this problem, but have a better understanding of the oop-php world.

Comment: It's impossible to give you an answer, if you don't tell us what  `$this->analysis [$report_id]` is. `$this->analysis [$report_id] ->subject${iterator} = $subject;` is highly irregular, but it could be valid code under certain very specific situations. And what do you mean by `the application is written procedural-style`?

Comment: Need more: `$this->analysis [$report_id]` is in no way a `standard object`. If it's an object, then it's one  that implements the [ArrayAccess interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php). Or it could be a simple array. `$this->analysis [$report_id] ->subject0 = "foo"` Does this work? You may saw it in code, but have you verified that it works? There are two ways that this could work: 1) The object in `$this->analysis [$report_id]` has public properties for every subject or 2) it uses the magic setter.

Comment: In any case it's not standard behaviour and you must be certain it works. And what does `The part after the -> doesn't work.` mean? Do you get an error or a notice (you should have [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at E_ALL to see the notices) - or does it just not work, i.e. no errors but when you examine `$this->analysis [$report_id]` it just doesn't hold the values you gave it?

Comment: That's a highly specific question to just consider it as "pseudocode".

Comment: Look up PHP's [magic __set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea where the $report_id come from ...
Usually, I will do this :-

```
$iterator = $i = 0;
foreach ($categories as $subject)
{
  $var = "subject{$i}";
  $this->analysis [$report_id]->$var =  $subject;
  ++$i;
  if ($i >= 10)
  {
    // what is your error?
  }
}
```

make use of variable to represent variable variable
docs :- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: I haven't got a clue what I missed yesterday, I thought I tried this approach, but clearly I hadn't.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments: You need to add a magic `__set()` to the class whose objects live in `$this->analysis [$report_id]`. Let's call the class `HelloWorld` for convenience. Your code would be something like:

```
class HelloWorld {

    private $data = array();

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;        
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        if( !array_key_exists($key, $this->data) ) {
            return null; // or throw an exception
        }

        return $this->data[$key];        
    }

}
```

The combination of a magic setter and getter essentially provides dynamic class properties via property overloading. So now you can do this:

```
$foo = new HelloWorld()
$foo->bar = "foobar";
echo $foo->bar;
```

Where "foobar" is stored in the `HelloWorld::$data` array with key `bar`. And of course now this:

```
$iterator=0;
foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
    $property = "subject{$iterator}";

    $this->analysis[$report_id]->$property = $subject;
    $iterator++;
}
```

should work fine. If the `$subjects` array's keys are ordered integers, you could also rewrite as:

```
foreach ($subjects as $iterator => $subject) {
    $property = "subject{$iterator}";

    $this->analysis[$report_id]->$property = $subject;
}
```

The two essential manual pages to understand the above are:

- [Magic Methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)
- [Method and property overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) and

Comment: thanks for helping me clearing up my question (with your helpful comments on it) and explaining overloading to me. There is so much more to learn!